# check if values exist in table - trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to write trigger which will control if a record is already in table or not. If is the record already in table (compare for example by name), so current record set valid='False' and insert new. Is there any way?

This is my idea, but it doesn't work.

```
create or replace TRIGGER 
Check_r
  before insert on t$customer
  FOR each ROW
  declare
  v_dup number;
  v_com number;
  v_id number;
  v_id_new number; 
  begin
  v_date:=SYSDATE;
      select count(id) INTO v_dup from t$customer where surname=:NEW.surname ;
      select count(id) INTO v_com from t$customer where firstname =:NEW.firstname and
      address=:NEW.address;
      select id into v_id from t$customer where surname=:NEW.surname;
   if v_dup > 0 and v_com=0  then
   v_id_new:= m$_GET_ID; -- get id
   update t$customer set valid = 'False' where id = v_id;
   insert into t$customer ( id, surname ,firstname, valid, address ) values (v_id_new,:NEW.surname ,:NEW.firstname, :NEW.valid, :NEW.address);
   end if;
   if v_dup = 0 then
   v_id_new:= m$_GET_ID;  -- get id
   insert into t$customer ( id, surname ,firstname, valid , address) values (v_id_new,:NEW.surname ,:NEW.firstname, :NEW.valid, :NEW.address);
   end if;
  end;
```

Comment: I won't do that with triggers.

Comment: A trigger on table A cannot normally query table A as the data for that table is currently in flux. And the trigger can not also then do another insert/update into the same table. You are coding in a trigger that assumes that this row is being inserted that, under the right circumstances, it should be inserted again. There ARE workarounds, but for what you are asking I would recommend coding a PL/SQL Procedure that your App calls that checks and then does the insert or update as appropriate.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @MichaelBroughton, not fully correct, a **Row-Level** Trigger (i.e. with `FOR EACH ROW` clause) cannot update/select the own table. Statement-Level trigger of composite triggers can do that.

Comment: @Werngried - yes, you are absolutely correct and I probably should have added that note to the OP for reference, although its not much help without jumping through hoops for the row-level operation that he is describing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a compound trigger, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_r
    FOR INSERT ON t$customer
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

    TYPE customerRecordType IS RECORD(
        surname t$customer.surname%TYPE,
        firstname t$customer.firstname%TYPE, 
        address t$customer.address%TYPE,
        ID nubmer);
    TYPE customerTableType IS TABLE OF customerRecordType;
    customerTable customerTableType := customerTableType();

    n NUMBER;

BEFORE STATEMENT IS   
BEGIN       
    customerTable.DELETE; -- not requried, just for better understanding
END STATEMENT;


BEFORE EACH ROW IS   
BEGIN       
    customerTable.EXTEND;
    customerTable(customerTable.LAST).surname := :NEW.surname;
    customerTable(customerTable.LAST).firstname := :NEW.firstname;
    customerTable(customerTable.LAST).address := :NEW.address;
    customerTable(customerTable.LAST).ID := m$_GET_ID;
    :NEW.ID := customerTable(customerTable.LAST).ID;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS 
BEGIN
    FOR i IN customerTable.FIRST..customerTable.LAST LOOP       
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n
        FROM t$customer
        WHERE surname = customerTable(i).surname;       
        IF n > 1 THEN
            UPDATE t$customer
            SET valid = 'False'
            WHERE surname = customerTable(i).surname;
        END IF;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n
        FROM t$customer
        WHERE firstname = customerTable(i).firstname
            AND address = customerTable(i).address;
        IF n > 1 THEN
            UPDATE t$customer
            SET valid = 'False'
            WHERE firstname = customerTable(i).firstname
                AND address = customerTable(i).address
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END AFTER STATEMENT;    

END;
/
```

Please note, this solution is ugly and poor in terms of performance!
But it should give you an impression how it works.

In general you should put all this into a PL/SQL Procedure instead of a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is trigger for insert. you don't need to write insert statement.

Second, you need to update old record. Just update it with your where clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_r
before insert on t$customer
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE t$customer set valid = 'False' 
  WHERE surname = :NEW.surname 
  AND firstname =:NEW.firstname;
:NEW.id := m$_GET_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Won't work - you can't update the table on which the trigger fires ("table is mutating...")